# How to remove default small-sized Google Map marker while building navigation app

Tags: android, navigation, google-maps-markers

I am using the below code to draw a marker on Google Maps in a android navigation app.

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
  new MarkerOptions().position(current)
                     .anchor(0.5f, 0.3f)
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(
                             R.drawable.navigation_marker)));
```

This marker appears successfully, but the default small-sized marker does not get removed. So, eventually I have two markers at the same time. Can you please help on how to remove the default marker?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "the blue dot" or "my location", you will have to completly remove it using `GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled` and use your own `LocationClient` to update user's current position.

Comment: Thanks. The dot and arrow are both removed.